# Facebook page not showing in search results on FB

Tags: facebook

The following page is not showing in search results in FB search when the name is entered: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Sal%C3%B3n-kr%C3%A1sy-B-Beautiful/192629294098564. It is indexed in Google and it is public, not hidden. The page was dead for about one year after creation—no content was added to it. Results show when you are an admin of the page or a fan, but not for stragners.

Comment: Hi there, I spent a while looking at this and I've come up with nothing beyond checking that page visibility box is unchecked. Facebook developers support is run on our sister site stackoverflow.com I think you'll stand a better chance of obtaining help there.

Comment: thanx, thought it's not really a programming question so it might not be suitable for stackoverflow... what I have found out that FB blocks some features until you have 25 fans, so i'll try to get more fans in there at first...

Comment: @MichalPlško yes you're right about SO. You might want to take a look at http://jobsfor10.com/ if you need fans quickly.

Comment: thnx, but not really, I have enough friends on my profile to get it somwhere... and it's not my business so I don't want to care that much about it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your place shows now.

[image: Place in search]

Normally for fans and admins, Facebook will push the results upwards. If you don't see it in the dropdown try "See more results for Pagename". It could also be a matter of activity and age of page.